# Create ReadOnlyCollection<IDisposable> from e.g. List<FileStream>

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to create a ReadOnlyCollection without creating a copy of the list? Since the elements can be casted to its base class it should be safe for ReadOnlyCollection to return not the concrete type but the implemented interface.

**Edit1** Adapted Code to show that I need to return IList to keep API compatibility.

```
public class Program : IDisposable
{
   List<Program> Programs = new List<Program>();

   public IList<IDisposable> Getter
   {
        get
        {
            var readOnly = new ReadOnlyCollection<IDisposable>(Programs);
            return readOnly;
        }
   }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

This will not compile for obvious reasons but is there no e.g.

```
ReadOnlyCollectionCast<Program,IDisposable>
```

which will cast to IDisposable in the getter?

A bit more history how I got there. I did refactor a class did have `List<IDisposable>` as class member. I needed for better serialization perf the concrete type in the data container. Changing the private field from `List<IDisposable>` to `List<Program>` is no problem but the public property should stay unchanged and still return an `IList<IDisposable>` as a read only list.

Answer (score 1):

well you can always use Linq.
`programs.Cast<IDisposable>()` gives you an `IEnumerable<IDisposable>`

EDIT:
If you really need to return an IList but want to actually return some read only collection:

`return new ReadOnlyCollection<IDisposable>( programs.Cast<IDisposable>().ToList() );`

Comment: new ReadOnlyCollection<IDisposable>(Programs.Cast<IDisposable>()); will not compile because it expects an IList<T> and not an IEnumerable<T>. Makes somehow sense because IEnumerable is already immutable.

Answer (score 0):

No casting is needed if you use an interface `List` as below:

```
List<IDisposable> programs = new List<IDisposable>();
programs.Add(new Program());
```

Do this to return it as readonly:

```
public IEnumerable<IDisposable> GetReadOlnly() 
{
    return programs.Skip(0);
}
```

To return a readonly `IList`:

```
public IList<IDisposable> GetReadOlnly() 
{
    return programs.AsReadOnly();
}
```

Comment: Nice idea but I need to return an IList<IDisposable> in a public getter which needs to be kept for API compat reasons.

Comment: The problem is that I do not have an IDisposable List but a list of a concrete class. That is the problem.

Comment: Why don't you do it the way I have in my answer? It is a list of IDisposable but contains the concrete types. I dont think you have read my answer carefully.

Comment: No it is not a list of IDisposables. It is a list of Program instances which implement IDisposable. The is the original problem statement of my question.

Comment: Well why don't you change it to a list of IDisposable? Is there a reason? I understand if you have a reason but I need the reason before I suggest a solution.

Comment: Have you read the updated question? I was refactoring a class which has some public API contracts I cannot change without pretty big efforts.

Comment: Yes I have and clearly their is miscommunication here. My answer will work if used properly. Nonetheless, you can do this as an alternative: `programs.Cast<IDisposable>().ToList().AsReadOnly();`

Comment: This involves copying the list which is not what I want for performance reasons. I still think you did not read all the constraints. For perf reasons List<IDisposable> needed to be changed to List<Programs> but the return type in the getter needs to be IList<IDisposable> as read only list but not as a copy.